# Unit Testing of Method With Generic Type Argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generic-type-argument

I have a system in which all my classes extend the base class `Sol.Data.Object`. In this base class I have one method for retrieving data from database:

```
public static ObjectType ReadById<ObjectType>(string schema, long id)
{
    SqlCommand command = User.CreateCommand(string.Format("{1}.Retrieve{0}",
                                            typeof(ObjectType).Name,
                                            schema),
                                            new SqlParameter("@ID", id));
       .....
}
```

I will call this method for example like this:
     `Sol.Movie.ReadId("dbo", 2)`

I used Visual Studio 2010 to create a unit test for this method:

```
public void ReadByIdTestHelper<ObjectType>()
{
    string schema = "dbo";
    long id = 1;
    ObjectType expected = default(ObjectType); //What should I put in here?!
    ObjectType actual;
    actual = Sol.Data.Object.ReadById<ObjectType>(schema, id);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
}

[TestMethod()]
public void ReadByIdTest()
{
    ReadByIdTestHelper<Sol.Movie>();
}
```

How should I define expected type? I tried `typeof(ObjectType)` but it gives me compile error.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this method to fix the problem:

```
public void ReadByIdTestHelper<ObjectType>()
{
    string schema = "dbo";
    long id = 1;
    Sol.Movie movie = new Movie();
    ObjectType actual;
    actual = Sol.Data.Object.ReadById<ObjectType>(schema, id);
    Assert.AreEqual((actual is ObjectType), true);
}

[TestMethod()]
public void ReadByIdTest()
{
    ReadByIdTestHelper<Sol.Movie>();
}
```

Don't know whether this is the best way to do this though.

Comment: You can. Please look at [Why Can’t I Accept My Own Answer?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer/). I believe you have to wait 48 hours then you will be able to accept.

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk sure thing! I will wait 48 hours.